# Rails fallback for nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resources, nested, fallback

I have a Post model which belongs to a User.
I display the Username like this:
`@post.user.name` If a user cancels their account, it will no longer work because the user is nil.
Is there a way to have a fallback user (e.g. "Deleted user")?

I though about disabling users instead of deleting them, but in some cases i might want to delete them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a concept called Null Pattern, you could implement something like this

```
class NullAuthor
  def name
    "Deleted user"
  end
end
```

and you would use it like this inside your ActiveRecord model

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  def author
    @author ||= if user.present?
                  user
                else
                  NullAuthor.new
                end
  end
end
```

In this way, you never have to check if the post user is nil or not :)

Comment: Awesome! thank you.
I ended up setting it to a (placeholder) user that can't be deleted.